# Find and Replace text in MongoDB Trigger

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I wrote a function in Nodejs to push the document to a different collection on update. But I am not able to do a find and replace before insert to the new collection.

```
exports = function(changeEvent) {
  const collectionAcc = context.services.get("new-collection").db("new-db").collection("new-collection");
  const doc = changeEvent.fullDocument;
  if(doc !== null || doc !== undefined) {
    console.log(doc);
    const res = collectionAcc.insertOne(doc);
  }
};
```

How can I find and replace a text in doc object